# Next steps to find the cause of Ember-CLI/Broccoli Plugin error during build

Tags: node.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

This happens on a Win 8.1 PC, as a result of "ember serve", with no modifications done after an error free, ember new MyApp.

From my research:

*"Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink"*  means that there is a permissions issue.
So I made sure my Windows 8.1 local security policy is set to admin and I'm running my cmd window with admin privileges. I've also reinstalled and updated Ember-CLI and NPM, globally. I'm not sure what else to try.

Also, the build is very slow, over 5 minutes on a normally fast PC. I have ember-cli-windows installed and it's still very slow.

Editorial comment: This seems like a pretty big fail for a "system" fresh out of the box. If it's this buggy without even adding new code... maybe I should invest time with Angular 2.0?

```
D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp>ember s
version: 2.4.2
The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel: Funnel: index.html] failed with:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\app' -> 'D:\
MyAppEmber\MyApp\tmp\funnel-input_base_path-by5U4Ewi.tmp\0'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:945:18)
    at symlinkWindows (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:90:16)
    at symlinkOrCopySync (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:56:5)
    at D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\read_compat.js:58:9
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:376:9)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at Funnel.Plugin (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
    at new Funnel (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:44:10)
    at EmberApp.index (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:595:15)
    at EmberApp.toArray (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1541:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1564:30)
    at module.exports (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (D:\MyAppEmber\MyApp\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:15:19)
```

Comment: have you had any success?

Comment: no luck.  I reinstalled all of it, per the Ember website instructions, and I get the same error.   I have no idea how to trouble-shoot this.

Comment: Update-not much to go on, but the error has something to do with it being on a mapped drive. I set up a project on a local partition on the same machine (which is a virtual machine) and it worked.

Comment: I believe I have later found out that atom is having issues on windows by locking folders which have been opened in the projects sidebar. I have since stopped using this plugin so can't confirm meddling with this changes things

Comment: I'm having the same issue except it is happening inside of my docker container

Comment: are you missing an `app/index.html` or `tests/index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

**Try running command prompt in administrator mode. It worked for me**

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that.
"...local security policy is set to admin and I'm running my cmd window with admin privileges. "